# How are one-click installers working? suggestions for work plan

Tags: php, cpanel, web-platform-installer

I would like to create a one click installer script for cpanel users.
I know of some applications for this issue, like installatron.com, softaculous.com etc. cpanel users just click and install a php script within the few seconds.

well, thats what i would like to do. How do they do this job within the few seconds? 
php scripts need mysql user name, password. and also auto installer must copy files to the user's ftp account. They gotta have some technics which I don't know.

Does anyone know how they work? I'd like to make a job plan. I really need your ideas and suggestions. I googled so much, however did not find any nice thing.

Comment: you could also make a snapshot of fresh install files and db. put it in some place on the server. when user click install, those files copied and sql inserted in new database.

Comment: great idea :) i do same job when i move my website to another hosting. copy files and insert database.. i can do this job with php curl and some api.. thank you mate.. thanks. this is a nice technic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying files is not a problem. The software packages can already be downloaded and set ready for CPanel. Maybe they are even installed already, so all that's needed to do is do a little configuration. So the speed makes sense.

CPanel already knows lots of settings for the database so it can configure the application itself, as long as it knows how.

I think you'd best read [CPanel's guide on integrating your own software](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome), which I found by just googling for 'CPanel installation script'. And of course take a peek at the source of other installers.

Comment: thanks for ideas. "take a peek at the source of other installers." this part is very helpfull. im gonna check out their source codes.. thank you. great idea. i must download their copies..